# how to install multi versons of google chrome browser in PC?

Tags: web-development

how to install multi versons of google chrome browser in PC?
I want to test my web site in defferent versons of chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Install Google Chrome Canary alongside the stable/regular one. Canary is like a always-in-beta version with the latest in-development features and fixes.